# Request failed with status code 500 error. When making form post of multiForm data in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, http-status-code-500

I am having a problem sending my file / photo element of my form. When the POST hits the backend it looks like it is posting OK however the form screen doesn't do anything when I click submit and the web dev console flags a "request failed with a status code 500" error.

If my backend API is working correctly is this likely are CORS error? The filepath for the routes are the same in my backend route folder and the axios post request on my form component. Also my IDE terminal is flagging that the correct text from the posting is hitting the backend (I am aware I need to fix the userID but I can do this myself). The file is also hitting the folder it is meant to go into but just not hitting my Postgres/ pgAdmin database.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
    // state for the current field value
    const [article, setArticle] = useState({
        articleTitle: ``,
        articleTypeID: ``,
        articleContent: ``,
        // photos: undefined,
        userID: ``,
        error: ``,
    });

    const [photos, setPhotos] = useState({
        photos: null
    })

    const handleChange = (property) => (e) => {
        setArticle({
            // override the changed property and keep the rest
            ...article,
            [property]: e.target.value,
        });
    }

    const handleChangeInt = (property) => (e) => {
        setArticle({
            // override the changed property and keep the rest
            ...article,
            [property]: parseInt(e.target.value),
        });
    }

    const handleChangeFile = (photos) => (e) => {
        this.setState({
            selectedFiles: e.target.photos,
        })
    }
    // get access to dispatch
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    // useEffect with an empty dependency array is the same as componentDidMount
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(requireFieldData());
    }, []);

    function handleSubmitArticle(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("articleTitle", article.articleTitle);
        formData.append("articleContent", article.articleContent);
        formData.append("userID", article.userID);
        formData.append("articleTypeID", article.articleTypeID);
        formData.append("photos", photos);
        axios.post("http://localhost:5002/api/article/createarticle", formData);
    }

    const classes = useStyles;

return (

    <div>

    <AppBar title="Enter your dive details"></AppBar>
    <form
        class="mt-4"
        id="articleForm"
        method="POST"
        enctype="multipart/form-data"
        onSubmit={handleSubmitArticle}>
        <>
            <Grid container spacing={3}
                  direction="row"
                  justify="center"
                  alignItems="center">
                <Grid item xs={10}>
                     <TextField
                      placeholder="Article-Title"
                      label="Article Title"
                      name="articleTitle"
                      margin="normal"
                      value={article.articleTitle}
                      onChange={handleChange("articleTitle")}
                      fullWidth/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={5}>
                    <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                        <TextField
                            placeholder="Author-User-Number"
                            label="AuthorUserNumber"
                            // defaultValue={props.user.userID}
                            margin="normal"
                            value={props.user.userID}
                            onChange={handleChangeInt("userID")}
                            fullWidth/>
                    </FormControl>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={5}>
                    <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                        <PopulateDropdown
                            dataList={articleTypeList}
                            titleProperty={"articleType"}
                            valueProperty={"articleTypeID"}
                            label="Article Type"
                            placeholder="Select article type"
                            value={article.articleTypeID}
                            onChange={handleChangeInt("articleTypeID")}/>
                    </FormControl>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={10}>
                    <FormControl fullWidth className={classes.formControl}>
                        <TextField
                            placeholder="Article Content"
                            label="ArticleContent"
                            name="articleContent"
                            value={article.articleContent}
                            onChange={handleChange("articleContent")}
                            multiline
                            rowsMax={6}
                            fullWidth/>
                    </FormControl>
                </Grid>
                <br />
                <Grid item xs={10}>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <label for="photos">Photo Upload</label>
                        <input
                            type="file"
                            name="photos"
                            id="photos"
                            // value={article.photos}
                            onChange={(e) => {
                                setPhotos(e.target.files?.[0]);
                            }}
                                />
                    </div>
                </Grid>
                <br />
                <Grid item xs={8} md={6}>
                    <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                        Submit</Button>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
    </>
    </form>
```

**Update**

Could this be something to do with the way my backend route handle formData? The error message seems to indicate an axios error.

```
//  create article
    app.post('/api/article/createarticle', upload.single("photos"), controller.createArticle);
```

**Update**

I already have Multer added to the route in my backend. Do I have to do anything other than the upload part? The backend API works perfectly so I didn't think it was anything to do with the backend. The Postman form data API works so I assumed it handled form data ok.

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: './assets/article/' })

module.exports = function(app) {

    app.post('/api/article/createarticle', upload.single("photos"), controller.createArticle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get to the cause of the problem. My form data needed some config logic to handle form data like below.

```
function handleSubmitArticle(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("articleTitle", article.articleTitle);
        formData.append("articleContent", article.articleContent);
        formData.append("userID", article.userID);
        formData.append("articleTypeID", article.articleTypeID);
        formData.append("photos", photos);
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        };
        axios.post("http://localhost:5002/api/article/createarticle", formData, config);
    }
```

I also needed to add a method to handle files into my onChange part of the input for the photos.

```
<label for="photos">Photo Upload</label>
                        <input
                            type="file"
                            name="photos"
                            id="photos"
                            // value={article.photos}
                            onChange={(e) => {
                                console.log(e.target.files)
                                if (e.target.files && e.target.files[0]) {
                                    let img = e.target.files[0];
                                    setPhotos(img)
                                }
                                // setPhotos(e.target.photos.[0]);
                            }}
                                />
```

Answer (score 2):

**The problem**:

From this error message you can see that your request body was parsed as `JSON`:
[image].

But you are sending `FormData`, which is of type `multipart/form-data`.

Express comes with [`body-parser`](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html), which can't process *multipart* bodies:

> This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in the following modules:
>
> - busboy and connect-busboy
> - multiparty and connect-multiparty
> - formidable
> - multer

---

**Solutions**:

1. Send JSON data. You don't really need form data unless you have complicated things like file inputs

   ```
   axios.post("http://localhost:5002/api/article/createarticle", article)
   //== Plain JS object which will be converted to JSON string ========^
   ```
2. Use a middle ware mentioned above that can handle form data. For example mutler:

   ```
    var express = require('express')
    var app = express()
    var multer  = require('multer')
    var upload = multer()

    app.post('/createarticle', upload.none(), function (req, res, next) {
         // req.body contains the text fields
    })
   ```

Comment: I have several forms with text, ints, co-ordinates and images so I thought form data was the way to go. I already have Multer in my backend so I think the problem is something to do with my front-end.

Answer (score 1):

It seems something like [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) is required on the backend side